# SSL certificate error installing ruby via rvm

Tags: ruby, ssl

I am trying to install ruby using rvm, and I am getting the following output related to an SSL certificate error:

`rvm install 2.6.3`

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/11.2/x86_64/ruby-2.6.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.6.3 - #downloading ruby-2.6.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.6.3 - #extracting ruby-2.6.3 to /Users/user/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.3 - please wait
ruby-2.6.3 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.6.3 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.6.3 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.6.3 - #installing - please wait
ruby-2.6.3 - #making binaries executable - please wait
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'rubygems.org'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
There was an error while trying to resolve rubygems version for 'latest'. 
Halting the installation.
```

If anyone has any idea how to get around this error, a response would really be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. seems that you have connection problem to rubygems.org,  make sure you have a good internet connection so that the files needed by installation could be downloaded.
2. forget RVM, use rbenv instead.
3. If you still get this kind of issue( ssl cert related when downloading from rubygems.org or ruby-lang.org), try to choose a new mirror of rvm/rbenv. e.g. for example, people in China may choose `taobao` mirror when install:  `git clone https://github.com/andorchen/rbenv-taobao-mirror.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-taobao-mirror`